# GitHub Actions: Docker Compose Not Setting Environment Variables for My Spring Boot Docker Image

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions

I converted the .env file to base64 and added it to GitHub secrets. In my action, I converted it to a .env.stage file and attached it to the Docker Compose command, as shown below:

```
- name: "Decode and Export Environment File"
  run: |
    echo "${{ secrets.ENV_STAGE }}" | base64 -d > .env.stage
- name: "Print file contents"
  run: |
    cat .env.stage
- name: "Build Docker Image"
  run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.stage.yml --env-file .env.stage up --build -d
- name: "Push to DockerHub"
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: myapp/myapp:${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}, myapp/myapp-stage:latest
```

Docker compose looks like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env.stage
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    restart: always
```

When I run the action, everything works well, but the environment configurations are not set in the application.yml file. I can see the .env.stage file when I call the 'cat' command.

When I log the Docker logs, I can see the application console logs as follows:

```
myapp-api-1 | [INFO ] 2024-01-26 08:03:42,972 [main] MyAppApplication- The following 1 profile is active: "${SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVES}
```

Everything works perfectly locally. I echoed the file with the base64 string using the command:

```
echo "<base64_string>" | base64 -d > .env.stage
```

and created the file. After that, I ran the Docker Compose command,

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.stage.yml --env-file .env.stage up --build
```

which is in the action, and everything works perfectly. However, it is not working in the action?

Comment: Does `cat .env.stage` print the correct output? Nothing is missing or changed?

Comment: yes, it printed everything correctly

Comment: Right. Can you please try to emulate the same thing locally by setting the Base64 of your `.env` file to an env var e.g. `ENV_STAGE` and then use that to recreate it with `echo "$ENV_STAGE" | base64 -d > .env.stage`?

Comment: ```cat .env | base64 > .env.base64```
```export ENV_STAGE=$(cat .env.base64)```
```echo "$ENV_STAGE" | base64 -d > .env.stage```
```docker-compose -f docker-compose.stage.yml --env-file .env.stage up --build```

if i understand correctly, i followed the above steps like this, and it also worked without any issues.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a public repo. That'll be easier to reproduce and identify the issue. Apparently, the information you've provided in your question seems to be correct and it should work.